# How to convert g++ commands to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, g++, clion

I know this question might be a bit obscure, but I'm building a project in CLion and I'm fairly new to C++.

The sample project that came with the API ran these commands to build the project:

```
g++ -I. -I../../cpp/include -D__UNIX__  -Wno-deprecated  -m64 -c searcher.cpp -o searcher.o
g++ -o ../../../bin64/sercher64 dtsearch.o dtsviewr.o searcher.o settings.o xmlMaker.o dstring.o dfile.o -L../../../bin64 -ldtsearch64 -lz
```

CLion has a CMakeLists.txt file and I'm trying to figure out how to set these options to my project will compile.

Here is what I have so far. I was able to add the include_directories, and the -D, -W, and -m flags. But the rest error when I attempt to add them.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(searcher)

include_directories(.)
include_directories(../../cpp/include)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D__UNIX__  -Wno-deprecated  -m64")

set(SOURCE_FILES searcher.cpp)
add_executable(searcher ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Any direction will be helpful.

Comment: Hello, this has nothing to do with CLion actually. You need to understand cmake. For example, have a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.2/quick-cmake-tutorial.html and https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/

Comment: @marco.m thanks I will take a look at those to see if I'm lead in the right direction.